# /usr/sbin/uninstall? What is it/what does it do?

Tags: macos, unix

There's a `/usr/sbin/uninstall` command on my system. What does it do? There is no `man` page, and running it says

1. "`You must be root to run this tool.`",
2. and (after `sudo uninstall -h`) it says "`URL is not uninstallable: -h`".

If I just run `sudo uninstall`, it says "`uninstall file_urls ...`"

I'm curious!

Comment: idk what it is, but have a little bit more information. The command first appears in 10.7 Lion, and there is also a framework and daemon in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Uninstall.framework/Versions/A/Resources/uninstalld and a matching plist in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.uninstalld.plist

Comment: My guess is for the Mac App Store (especially with a daemon) ... but I really don't have any evidence to back that up.

Comment: That was my guess as well, but App Store appeared in Snow Leopard with a couple daemons that could handle that, and uninstall did not appear in any update for Snow Leopard, which still uses App Store (unless you do as I do and [disable it](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13797/how-to-update-app-store-application-from-command-line/128150#128150)). This does not preclude the possiblity, and it is still my strong suspicion... but I have no evidence.

Comment: @chillin Well, maybe it needs to be globalized for Launchpad, etc?

Comment: @people I've tried com.apple.[etc]-style (aka Java-style) URLs, but it didn't take them. It also doesn't take iTunes web links, nor the Mac App Store links (my chosen test url: macappstores://itunes.apple.com/us/app/caffeine/id411246225, for Caffiene)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[0942v8653](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/67260/0942v8653)'s guess is right, `/usr/sbin/uninstall` is a command line uninstaller for Mac App Store apps.

The file URL must be specified as parameter. In my tests the path to the application did it:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/uninstall /Applications/Reeder.app
Preparing Uninstall...
Uninstall Began...
7%...
15%...
(...)
92%...
100%...
Uninstall Ended...
```

while non-Mac App Store apps couldn't be uninstalled:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/uninstall /Applications/Seashore.app 
URL is not uninstallable: /Applications/Seashore.app
```

Interestingly, although I ran the command with sudo it still asked me for administrator credentials:

[image]

`/usr/bin/uninstall` uses the Uninstall private framework:

```
$ otool -L /usr/sbin/uninstall 
/usr/sbin/uninstall:
(...)
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Uninstall.framework/Versions/A/Uninstall (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 202.0.0)
(...)
```

just like the Dock:

```
$ otool -L /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock | grep Uninstall
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Uninstall.framework/Versions/A/Uninstall (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 202.0.0)
```

That makes sense, because my tests showed that when an application is uninstalled inside Launchpad (by clicking the app’s delete button that appears when icons wiggle) `uninstall` is not used, but the Dock.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the investigation. (I wish it'd work for non-MAS apps, though.)